# How do I default optional fields in spyne?

Tags: option-type, spyne

Here is some Spyne/SOAP code where I'm returning one or two strings.  Is there a way to avoid having to set string2 to None to indicate that it's not present?

```
class TestResult(ComplexModel):
    """
    """
    string1 = Unicode
    string2 = Unicode(min_occurs=0, max_occurs=1)

    def __init__(self):
        # Say hello
        self.string1 = "Hello World"

        # Either of the following works
        #
        # self.string2 = "...from Paul"
        # self.string2 = None
        #
        # But omitting them doesn't.


class Test(ServiceBase):
    """
    """
    @srpc(Unicode, _returns=TestResult)
    def Test(Query):
        """
        """
        response = TestResult()

        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question really, please clarify.

`string2` will be returned explicitly as `xsi:null` when it has `min_occurs=1` if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

string2 is optional (min_occurs=0) but I have to explicitly set it to 'None' to have it omitted completely from the XML response. I am asking is there something that I'm missing that would allow me to have the code as written (i.e. string2 never explicitly set) and generate a valid response.
The background is that I'm having to support some XML where responses have large numbers of optional fields but I'm having to set a long list of them tom NULL - so I'm hoping I can be lazy and find a way to avoid having to do this ;-).